# Error cannot coerce array to object using Mulesoft

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to migrate data from one Database to another using Mulesoft's Anypoint Platform. To do that I'm selecting all the data from the first DB and passing it to a stored procedure that inserts it into the second one.
I'm sending the payload, which is an array with the table's data, and I want to insert each row at a time, however, i'm getting this error:

```sql
Message               : "Cannot coerce Array ([]) to Object
Trace:
  at main (Unknown)" evaluating expression: "output application/java
---
payload map(payload,indexOfPayload ) -> {
"LOG_CODE": payload.LOG_CODE,
"USER_CODE": payload.USER_CODE,
"LOG_DATE": payload.LOG_DATE,
"LOG_USER_ID": payload.LOG_USER_ID,
"LOG_EVENT": payload.LOG_EVENT,
"LOG_USER_EMAIL": payload.LOG_USER_EMAIL
}".
Error type            : MULE:EXPRESSION
Element               : Copy_of_LOG_TLOGMigrationFlow/processors/1/route/0/route/0/aggregator/processors/0 @ DatabaseConnectorPOC:businessLogic.xml:54 (Copy_of_Stored procedure)
Element XML           : 
 <db:stored-procedure doc:name="Copy_of_Stored procedure" doc:id="59c14834-c745-4aba-9acf-a1b3f9577aed" config-ref="Database_Config">
<db:sql>{call InsertIntoContent (:LOG_CODE, :USER_CODE, :LOG_EVENT, :LOG_USER_ID, :LOG_USER_EMAIL, :LOG_DATE)}</db:sql>
<db:input-parameters>#[output application/java
---
payload map(payload,indexOfPayload ) -> {
    "LOG_CODE": payload.LOG_CODE,
    "USER_CODE": payload.USER_CODE,
    "LOG_DATE": payload.LOG_DATE,
    "LOG_USER_ID": payload.LOG_USER_ID,
    "LOG_EVENT": payload.LOG_EVENT,
    "LOG_USER_EMAIL": payload.LOG_USER_EMAIL
}]</db:input-parameters>
</db:stored-procedure>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thank you!

Edit: I added a Transform Message with this content before Stored Procedure component.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload map(payload,indexOfPayload ) -> {
    LOG_CODE: 1,
    USER_CODE: 2,
    LOG_DATE: '5/1/2008 8:06:32 AM -07:00' as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"},
    LOG_USER_ID: 'AAA',
    LOG_EVENT: 'AAA',
    LOG_USER_EMAIL: 'AAA'
}
```

This is what my flow looks like:

```xml
</flow>
    <flow name="Copy_of_LOG_TLOGMigrationFlow" doc:id="1597fca5-5e9b-45f6-9c49-b8f9ee50c663" >
        <db:select doc:name="Copy_of_Select LOG_TLOG from Oracle DB" doc:id="d6ca57de-230c-4d7e-b011-10ba3cbb103d" config-ref="MYCAREER_DEV_DB" >
            <db:sql >SELECT * FROM LOG_TLOG</db:sql>
        </db:select>
        <batch:job jobName="Copy_of_MigrateLOG_TLOGBatchJob" doc:id="0220ea42-8f72-4be5-813f-df48a772cf0b" >
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Copy_of_MigrateLOG_TLOGBatchStep" doc:id="9bddfc72-07e3-4869-b9ad-26c89d945fe3" >
                    <batch:aggregator doc:name="Copy_of_LOG_TLOG Batch Aggregator" doc:id="47d150b2-e916-4f91-920c-9b46ec4de613" size="20" >
                        <ee:transform doc:name="Copy_of_Map LOG_TLOG from Oracle DB to fields of SQL Server DB" doc:id="4776778d-b98b-413e-a941-9f551a1efce8">
                            <ee:message>
                                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload map(payload,indexOfPayload ) -> {
    LOG_CODE: 1,
    USER_CODE: 2,
    LOG_DATE: '5/1/2008 8:06:32 AM -07:00' as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"},
    LOG_USER_ID: 'AAA',
    LOG_EVENT: 'AAA',
    LOG_USER_EMAIL: 'AAA'
}]]></ee:set-payload>
                            </ee:message>
                        </ee:transform>
                        <db:stored-procedure doc:name="Copy_of_Stored procedure" doc:id="59c14834-c745-4aba-9acf-a1b3f9577aed" config-ref="Database_Config">
                            <db:sql>{call InsertIntoContent (:LOG_CODE, :USER_CODE, :LOG_EVENT, :LOG_USER_ID, :LOG_USER_EMAIL, :LOG_DATE)}</db:sql>
                            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
 {
    "LOG_CODE": payload.LOG_CODE,
    "USER_CODE": payload.USER_CODE,
    "LOG_DATE": payload.LOG_DATE,
    "LOG_USER_ID": payload.LOG_USER_ID,
    "LOG_EVENT": payload.LOG_EVENT,
    "LOG_USER_EMAIL": payload.LOG_USER_EMAIL
}]]]></db:input-parameters>
                        </db:stored-procedure>
                    </batch:aggregator>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
            <batch:on-complete >
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Copy_of_Logger" doc:id="8b5512f4-9925-4034-99d1-98f82bd34d06" message="LOG_TLOG finished data migration." />
            </batch:on-complete>
        </batch:job>
    </flow>

</mule>
```

Comment: Its a type missmatch @ooz; a part of your expression expects an `Array` but you are getting an `Object`.    I say extrapolate the DW expression into a `Transform Message` processor set a couple of sample data and see what the preview outputs.   If you provide sample data and the code we should be able to fix it for you.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I added the message processor component to the flow with sample data as you suggested but its giving me the same error.

Comment: From looking at your flow it looks like you're trying to run the stored procedure on 20 records in a list. I would try to wrap a for-each scope around your stored procedure call that calls it for each of the records in a collection

Comment: Seems like that fixed it! Thank you so much for the help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-iterating from my comment. But this is occurring because after your transform message in your batch aggregate step, you have an arrayList of java objects. Your stored procedure is expecting 1 record object, so you either need to wrap your SP call in a `for-each` scope or don't use an aggregate step so you can map each record separately and make your SP call.

Comment: I wrapped the Stored Procedure around a for-each scope and it solved it! Thank you for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like payload.LOG_EVENT is an array. Message says array cannot coerce with object. All varaiables except LOG_EVENT are regular ones which means it is LOG_EVENT which is array.

Try to Log it and see what it is.

Comment: Wrapping the stored procedure around a for-each scope fixed it! But thank you for answering :)